# Discord Bot: How to exclude a certain channels

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, bots, discord.js

```
client.on('messageDelete', function (message) {
  if (message.channel.type === 'text') {
    var log = client.channels.cache.get("44444444444444444")
    if (log != null) {
      client.channels.cache.get('4444444444444').send('**DELETED** ' + `${message.author}` + '\: ' + message.cleanContent + ' ')
    }
  }
})
```

Here is my script for logging deleted messages.

How to exclude from this certain channels and/or certain users like bots?

 Should i use something like:

```js
if (message.channel.type === 'text') & channels... & users...
```

Comment: Yeah, something like that should work. You'll want to do something more like `if( message.channel.type === "text" && channels && users)`. Give it a shot and let us know if you have any problems with getting it running.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to store excluded channels and users in some sort of arrays and checking if message.author or message.channel is in one of this arrays. You can easly check if an author of a message is a bot by using author.bot property of User.

```
if (message.author.bot) return;
    channels.forEach(element => {
if (element == message.channel) return;
});
    users.forEach(element => {
if (element == message.author) return;
});
```